# How to add line-break in PHP file?

Tags: php

I tried every data in single line but I can't.

```
"First Name:  ".$first_name. 
"Last Name:  ".$first_name.
```

Tried:

```
$string = str_replace("<br>", "<br><br>", $string);
```

and

```
$string=nl2br($string);
```

and

```
\n
```

My all solutions doesn't work. How can I do it?

EDITED:
Now:

```
first_name last_name
```

Want:

```
first_name

last_name
```

Comment: It'd be a good idea to post all of your code so we can see what exactly you are doing and what kind of output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If displaying as HTML:

```
$string = "First Name: " . $first_name . "<br/>" .
          "Last Name: " . $last_name;
```

If displaying inside a textarea or similar:

```
$string = "First Name: " . $first_name . PHP_EOL .
          "Last Name: " . $last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the line break into the assignment statement:

```
$string = "First Name: " . $first_name . "<br>" .
          "Last Name: " . $last_name;
```

`str_replace` and `nl2br` didn't work because there was no line break in the string for them to replace.

Comment: thank you but  "<br>" . not working. I want every data in single line. When I put  "<br>" . its only has a space.

Comment: I don't understand why my answer doesn't work for you. If you're displaying this in a web browser, this will put the two names on separate lines, like in your question.

Answer (score 0):

use
$string="First Name: " . $first_name . "
" ."Last Name: " . $last_name;